# docker-compose build -> many "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" error's

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, synology

I am trying to run an instance of a docker container (django project) on my synology nas DS220+. After:

`docker-compose build`

I get this error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
[6138] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

My directory structure is:

```
     nas
     |-docker
     |  |-configurator
     |  |  |-accounts
     |  |  |-config
     |  |  |-pages
     |  |  |-static
     |  |  |-staticfiles
     |  |  |-templates
     |  |  |-docker-compose.yml
     |  |  |-Dockerfile
     |  |  |-manage.py
     |  |  |-Pipfile
     |  |  |-Pipfile.lock
     |  |  |-requirements.txt
     |  |-some_other_project
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /configurator/

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /configurator/
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /configurator/
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
 web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
  volumes:
   - .:/configurator/
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  depends_on:
   - db
  environment:
   - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=django secret key"
   - "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
   - "SENDGRID_API_KEY=my very secret api key"

 db:
  image: postgres:11
  volumes:
   - postgres_data:/configurator/data/postgresql/
  environment:
   - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
 postgres_data:
```

I am confused about the permission error. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Your dockerfile, you may need to install pip first

Answer (score 0):

I tried below for the similar issue on my SLES Linux machine to resolve issue:

I followed steps https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/